# Using a `.size()` as an array index

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, size, random-walk

Say I have a some code like:

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long int> > > posHistory;
posHistory pHist (1, vector<vector<long int>>(1, vector<long int>(1,0)));
```

that kept track of, for example:

- The number of dogs.
- The number of times takes a step.
- The position of each step. (step length of unity (1))

How could I add a position for each defecation?
I have:

direction = some random number between -dimensions and dimensions (say -2,2 for 2d)
tdof = translational degrees of freedom, essentially each axis.

```
for (unsigned int tdof = 0; tdof < dimensions; tdof++)
{
    if (fabs(direction) < tdof)
    {
        walkHist[(int) walkHist.back()][(int) walkHist[walkHist.back()].size()][tdof] = (long int) copysign(1, direction);
    }
}
```

The part that is giving me trouble is:

```
walkHist[walkHist.size()-1][walkHist[walkHist.size()-1].size()][ (long int) copysign(1, direction)];
```

And later in the code I have:

```
walkHist[(walkHist.size()-1)].push_back();
walkHist.push_back();
```

I'm fairly sure it's the conversion between size_type to an index that is the problem, but how could I rectify that?

I've tried casting, but that doesn't seem to work, although I may have just done it wrong.
In short, help?

### Edit 1

The first push back gives me an error:

```
saw.cpp:62:50: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<long int> >::push_back()’
```

### Edit 2

Hmm, it seems that `walkHist.at(walkHist.back()).size()` gives me:

```
saw.cpp:49:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<long int> > >::at(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::vector<std::vector<long int> > > >::value_type&)’
```

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: Does your vector of vectors have any elements in it?  If you attempt to use `size() - 1`, but `size()` is 0, you also have UB.

Comment: As long as the array is not empty then: `a[a.size()-1]` provides the same reference as `a.back()` which seems a lot easier to read. Also `push_back()` requires a parameter.

Comment: Thank you! And all vectors are initialized as 1 before the program begins. I didn't know about .back(), I'll use that now.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Added in the error, sorry. I have a habit of forgetting them. I'm new here, I'll learn >.<.

Comment: About your second edit: `walkHist.back()` is a `std::vector<std::vector<long>>`. The `at()` member function wants a _single value_, and you are trying to pass it a container. I think you're getting lost in all these nested vectors.

Comment: Yes well, I want the value of the last walk. Or the "current walk", so shouldn't `walkHist.back()` return the same thing as `.size()-1 ?`. And yeah, oh so very lost. Trust me haha. First time working with multidimensional vectors, but it can't be helped.

Edit - Damnit. Someone told me back would return the number of objects in the array -1, I should know better than to not RTFM before using something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `foo[foo.size()]` for a `std::vector<T> foo` accesses an element of `foo` just outside the range of `foo`: arrays in C and C++ are zero-based, i.e., you can access indices `0, ..., size()-1`. Accessing an element outside this range is undefined behavior.

Comment: I know that, that is why there are -1's in every place I access them.

Comment: @NictraSavios: Thanks for pointing that out but you are using one `size()` without a `-1`: the one on the left of the cast to `long int`! That is, I noted the `-1`s and also noted a missing one (seems I pay closer attention to your code than you do). Also note that `foo.size()-1` will be an illegal index in case `foo.size() == 0` (i.e., `foo.empty()`).

Comment: Thank you, the vectors are initialized as one and never resized, so I should be fine, but is there a command that would throw an error that could be caught should this happen?

And to the left of the long int cast is a case copy, that is actually improper syntax... although I fixed it now. ( I put the value to be assigned in the index place instead of assigning it.

Comment: @NictraSavios: If you want index bounds checking you can use [`std::vector::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) instead of `operator[]`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I'm not sure how to use `std::vector::at` with multidimensional arrays, that's why I didn't use it in the first place. I searched around a bit but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: @NictraSavios: `at()` returns a reference so you can chain them like `walkHist.at(1).at(2).at(3)`. It's ugly but not that different from doing `walkHist[1][2][3]`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Thank you, I'll implement that now.  I've also edited the OP with the error I get from the push_back().